# Как убрать application path при работе с Tomcat Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

При редиректах с под html теряется application name в URL и из-за этого не получается нормально работать с данными отправленными из формы на rest controller.
До отправки формы:

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/login
```

После получаем:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth?param1=value&param2=value
```

вместо

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/auth?param1=value&param2=value
```

Мне подсказали вариант - попробовать запустить приложение без application name, но как это сделать я не могу найти информации. Как правильно это всё реализовать?

Comment: просто указываете в appname = ''

Comment: как вы разворачиваете приложение?